# How to show success or error message block at the top of the page

Tags: magento2, messages

I need show success or error `messages` block at the top of the page before the `header` block. As of now it appears between the `breadcrumbs` and `main` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  Here is one which requires a little layout xml and a new template at a minimum…

**Layout**:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="core/template" name="top.messages" template="core/messages/top.phtml" before="-" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

**Template:**  `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/core/messages/top.phtml`

```
<?php $_messageCollection = $this->getMessagesBlock()->getMessageCollection() ?>

<?php if ($_messageCollection->count()): ?>
    <div>
        <?php
        echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml();
        $_messageCollection->clear();
        ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Alternate way**

add belwo line 
 at `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/Magento_Theme/laout/default.xml`

```
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    .......

    <move element="page.messages" destination="after.body.start"  after="-"/>

    ......

</page>
```

Comment: why we need to create new phtml? its possible to move elements using XML right?

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do this.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thank  you the alternate way method worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

```
<move element="page.messages" destination="after.body.start"  after="global_notices"/>
```

This will place it at the top of the page.